# mistake using read_delim column names don't match

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently using R for the first time in a year and feel a bit lost. I have trouble importing a messy csv of a time series. Indeed, when I run the following code, i get a mistake message :

```
 test_2 <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/Downloads/dataset_univarie.csv", sep = ";", 
 header = TRUE)
 View(test_2) 
 test_3 <- test_2[-(504:515),]
 View(test_3)
```

Until here, all good, but when I try to import the original dataset differently in order for R to understand the first column is a date column, in order to be able to work adequatly on the time series, I struggle :

```
 read.csv(file = "C:/Users/Downloads/dataset_univarie.csv")
 serie_elec <- read_delim("C:/Users/Downloads/dataset_univarie.csv"," ; ", 
                          escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols("Période" = 
 col_date(format = "%Y-%m"), "Production.brute.d.électricité.nucléaire..en.GWh." = 
 col_number()), trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Here is the message of error I get :

```
 Warning message:                                                                                                                  
 The following named parsers don't match the column names: Période, 
 Production.brute.d.électricité.nucléaire..en.GWh.
```

And thus, the dataframe I get isn't one (I want to get a two columns dataframe, like test_3) :

```
dput(head(serie_elec))
structure(list(`Période;Production brute d'électricité nucléaire (en GWh)` = c("2022- 
11;22951.429", 
 "2022-10;21465.026", "2022-09;19334.531", "2022-08;19319.365", 
 "2022-07;19923.664", "2022-06;21275.248")), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the head of my dataset for reproducibility (it is a time series of electricity production in France)

```
 structure(list(Période = c("2022-11", "2022-10", "2022-09", 
 "2022-08", "2022-07", "2022-06"), Production.brute.d.électricité.nucléaire..en.GWh. = 
 c(22951.429, 
 21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 21275.248)), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would changing `delim = " ; "` to `delim = ";"` fix the issue?

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't change the message of error...